# Word sequences to abbreviated forms

Tags: abbrev

Is there a way to change words or a sequence of words into abbreviated forms.  `about` to `ab`; `after` to `af`; `between` to `bt`?

And doing the reverse as well, with an abbreviated word showing a list showing of words in a drop-down like as in completion or shown in the mini-buffer.  Writing `hw` shows possible words (`how`).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to…

The answer to this type of question is always yes, if you apply enough elbow grease.

I’ll leave the actual implementation as an exercise for the reader. Or you can search online for answers to homework problems.

Comment: `Exercise for the reader` just means no details will be forthcoming.  I am more interested in the latter, from abbreviation giving possible words.